# How do I present the inside of a navigation controller from another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I have a navigation controller connecting two view controllers: let's call them view controller **A** and **B**. When I click on an item in table **A** it takes me to **B**. I want to add a new controller **C** and when I click on an item in **C** I want it to take me to **B**. And after it takes me to **B** I can still use the navigation bar on **B** to return to **A**.

How should I do that?

I tried to segue from **C** to **B** but the navigation bar just disappears. And segueing from **C** to the navigation controller takes me to **A** instead of **B**.

Comment: that sounds quite confusing. how would the user get to C? it sounds like this kind of flow would be strange for a user unless I am misunderstanding it

Comment: So basically I am trying to mimic the search function of yahoo fiance app. When you click on the search bar on the main screen(A), it takes you to the new search view(C), and when you click the results on C, it takes you to B. You can also click on items on A to get to B.

Comment: I think that might be just using a UISearchController and a search results controller

Comment: Please specify how you will goto C. This is incomplete question.

Comment: I goto C from clicking a button on A.

Comment: So if you want to go to C from A and when C dismisses you want B to be shown? Am I correct?

Comment: So A is the main view, it has a tableview and a button, click on the items of tableview takes you to B(detailview), and click on the button takes you to c(searchview). in C, there is also a table view displaying results, if you click on that it takes you to B. A and B are embedded in navigation controller, so there is a back button on B that takes you back to A.

Comment: An easy solution may be if A is the root view controller. Every time to use popToRootViewController when you are in B.